# Background with 100% viewport width inside fixed width container

Tags: html, css

I have a container with 1000px width. On of the design items has a background of full-width (see blue bar on the image). Is it possible to put such background without additional markup?

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

And the markup I'd like to use:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem...</p>
    <p class="bar">Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem...</p>
    <p>Lorem...</p>
    <p>Lorem...</p>
</div>
```

I tried to do it with absolutely positioned additional element and some extra tricks, like this:

```
.bar:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

It's almost good enough, except there's a problem to get it at the top of the container and not at the top of the contents of the blue bar. Plus, using extra element feels redundant.

It also can be done by placing the blue bar outside of the container, as parent and a child, but this way I will end up putting the 1000px value three times: for the div above the blue one, for the div inside blue one and for the div under the blue one.

Is there some way to achieve this effect to avoid repeating container's width and without any additional markup?

Comment: Can you show the markup?

Comment: @avejidah I updated the question.

Comment: The container is 1000px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is CSS `calc()` approach. Since the container is fixed width, so you can use negative margin to make `.bar` full viewport width, and use same amount of positive padding for the correction of the vertical alignment of the text box (optional).

I put it into a media query make sure to check it out in a larger window.

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXWYdY)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: pink;
  }
  .bar {
    margin: 0 calc(50% - 50vw);
    padding: 0 calc(50vw - 50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: gold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Lorem...</div>
  <div class="bar">Lorem</div>
  <div>Lorem...</div>
  <div>Lorem...</div>
  <div>Lorem...</div>
</div>
```

**Previous answer**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: pink;
  }
  .bar {
    margin: 0 calc((1000px - 100vw) / 2);
    padding: 0 calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: gold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Lorem...</div>
  <div class="bar">Lorem</div>
  <div>Lorem...</div>
  <div>Lorem...</div>
  <div>Lorem...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a feeling `calc` might be the answer here. I will take a shot and give a feedback.

Comment: What do you think about `margin: 0 calc((100vw - 100%) / -2);`? It seems to be working. Are you sure `padding` is needed? And can `1000px` be safely replaced with `100%`?

Comment: @RoboRobok Wow! that's even better. The padding is for matching the image you posted above (all "lorem" on the same vertical line), but yes you can drop it if you don't need it.

Comment: Let's see if it's good enough, but I was very happy to see it working. Not sure how stable it is though. Looks like at the moment it's perfect, not too wide, not too short.

Comment: Sorry it took me 3 years to select your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution would be to do something like this. You could still keep your original code but dont have to deal with absolutely position elements inside a body of text. much cleaner and you can edit the width of bar to be whatever you want, I merely made it 150%, use 100vw if you want max-width of the screen.

```
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  .bar {
    padding: 0 25%;
    width: 150%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blue;
    left: -25%;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why 150% and 25%? What if the screen is 5000px wide?

Comment: then use vw to get an X percentage of the screen. 150% is just an example, use whatever you want. If you want as well, you could add a max width on it in the event you get an extremely wide screen or something to that nature. 25% padding is to move it back left from where the width extends from the parent container so that will need to reflect what your width is. 90vw? padding would be calc((90vw - 1000px) / 2 * -1) or something like that

Comment: yep, it's pretty widely used. A very neat implementation for getting dynamic widths.

Comment: It's very calming to know it's common. I knew there is some way to do it without extra markup. :)

Comment: if you're ever in doubt, check caniuse.com, it's a great resource for browser compatibility. here's the calc method. https://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: Yeah, I know caniuse.com, but my doubt comes from somewhere else. I'm in doubt if 100% and negative margin is good enough in most cases. I don't want it to become too wide neither.

Comment: add the vw amount you want and then add a max-width attr to it as well preventing it from becoming to long. This is strictly personal as there is no technical problem with it, but i dont like using negative margins. Just seems hacky to me. either way, you're not going to run into issues.

Comment: I agree on negative margins/paddings feeling hacky, but on the other hand they work like magic sometimes :)

Comment: I would agree with that, they are a tidbit harder to manage in my experience but i just dislike margin in general so I'm a bit biased haha

Answer (score 1):

You can do it ike this: Use a relative position on that element, 100vw `width` and `left: calc((100vw - 500px) / 2 * -1);` to move it the left side by exactly the distance from the left window border: (where that pixel value is the width of the container - here I took 500px to fit it into the snippet)

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  left: calc((100vw - 500px) / 2 * -1);
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fa0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </p>

  <p class="bar">Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>

  <p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. </p>
```

Yet another solution would be to use negative margins using that same `calc` value. That way you can leave out `position: relative`:

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar {
  margin-left: calc((100vw - 500px) / -2);
  margin-right: calc((100vw - 500px) / -2);
  background-color: #fa0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </p>

  <p class="bar">Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>

  <p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. </p>
```

Comment: `/ 2 * -1` = `/ -2` :P

Answer (score 0):

On approach would be to simply put the width on the `p` elements rather than the container, and then make a more specific style for the `p.bar`.

```
.container p {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container p.bar {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Lorem...</p>
      <p class="bar">Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem...</p>
      <p>Lorem...</p>
      <p>Lorem...</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/IDiqCuampcDbA2nu8Ui6?p=preview

Comment: Putting width on container's children is short-sighted solution. You know it's just a mockup, right? The real layout may get much more complicated, but the problem of putting 100% bar is still there.

Comment: It doesn't seem short sighted to me.  To me it seems like restricting your container to 1000px when it clearly contains content that is wider than 1000px seems like poor design.  Using absolute position is what seems short-sided, given that it overrides the default flow layout.  Just glancing at the design, breaking the flow layout seems unnecessary and over complicated.  (E.g. what if you have two blue bars?)  But at any rate, this was just one possible way of doing it.

Comment: It doesn't contain elements wider than 1000px. It only contains the background that takes more space, which can be done any possible way according to me. In perfect case I guess that would be a pseudo-element.